# Route packets from Server A to B in Windows,B acts as a router

Tags: tunnel

I have two (Windows 2008 R2) servers, let's call them: `A` and `B`.

[image]

Server `A` is running a software server (in this example Apache HTTP).

Without touching or changing anything in Apache's configuration, I need all packets from `B` to be routed to server `A` and (very importantly) for Apache to know the real visitor's IP address. Meaning when visitor 192.168.1.2 contacts Apache on server `A` through tunnel `B`, apache should log ip 192.168.1.2 and NOT 192.168.1.100

To make things even more complicated, what if I want more servers like `B`.

[image]

Somehow, server `A` should always know the real visitor's IP address no matter which server `B` he connects from. All this should be done in network/OS level. (Meaning: not having to configure every software server with Proxy Socks firewall or anything like that)

I am a total newbie at tunneling and networking in general, and I am so confused as to what type of tunnels is needed to accomplish this in Windows server (VPN, GRE, IPSEC?). What should I be looking for ? And would it be possible to have servers `B` in Linux connected to server `A` in Windows in a very compatible way ? I've read in this site that it was possible in theory but very difficult in practice.

Any input about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are these frontend servers "B" supposed to be doing? What problem are they meant to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Based off your explanation, it seems like you more likely are looking for a reverse proxy/load balancer.  That would sit in your "B" location and traffic could be passed along to your A server(s).  The proxy could be deployed in a routed mode, or layer 2 mode.  Either way to ensure you get the original IP logged, you want to ensure x-forwarded-for headers are sent along from your proxy.

There are free proxy software products you could install, or appliances like KEMP, Netscaler, etc.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not necessarly looking for a load balancer as all the processing is done in server `A` alone.  I don't want to configure Apache in anyway or install any plugin for it. Apache was probably a bad example because this should apply to any other TCP server application as well.